# Show button when a specific input is compiled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a button (inside a div tag with id="next") until some specific input are compiled.

It is possible with jquery?

Here's my code:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
<div id="next1">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</div>
```

I've tried this jquery code, but when i've compiled name input, next button doesn't show!

```
if(!$('input[name=name]').val()){
    $('#next1').hide();
}
else {
    $('#next1').show();
}
```

What can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to check the value as the user types. To do that you can run your code within a `keyup` event handler. It can also be simplified to just using the `toggle()` method. Try this:

```js
$('#name').keyup(function() {
  $('#next1').toggle(this.value != '');
});
```

```css
#next1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
<div id="next1">
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</div>
```

Comment: but what can i do if i have two or more specific input like "name"?

Comment: Then use a common class on them all, not `id`

Comment: i've tried to use a class, but next button become visible when i compile first input field and not for all.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
$("input[name=name]").on("input",function(){
```

then you can check the input value by

```
$(this).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try the below code As you mentioned **specific input** I did this for if you type **Hello**

the button will be visible or not    Hope it helps ...

```js
 $(".fname").keyup(function (e) {
     if ($(this).val() == 'Hello') {
        $(".fname").not(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).next(".test").show();
     } else {
        $(".fname").removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).next(".test").hide();
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fname" class="fname">
            <input type="button" class="test" name="test" value="Hello!" style="display: none">
```